# Java Array store Objects random time

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, data-structures

An Array represents free seats in a parking. Now Cars (threads) are parking a random time and then leaving.

How can I know which slots are free? Do I have to iterate the Array each time to find a free slot or is there a better solution? Is it possible to create a second Array and store only the free indicies there?

Should I use a different datastructure than Array?

Comment: Just iterating through the array is going to be easiest; unless the parking lot has lots of spaces and/or you have a very tight time requirement, it will likely be sufficient.

Comment: Using a free list is a standard technique. Or just iterate.

Comment: In general, don't use arrays, but use the java collection framework. The counterpart of array is ArrayList. This has many useful functions that help handling the data.

Comment: @TedHopp¨how would I implement this? a second array and store the numbers of the free spots there?

Comment: You could keep a queue of free spot indices. Initialize it to contain every spot. Whenever you need to park a car, take the first element from the queue. Whenever a car leaves, put the index back onto the queue. (You could also use a stack. The difference would be that a stack reuses the most recently used parking space, while a queue uses the least recently used space.)

Comment: thanks I think this helps, so queue basically fifo and stack lifo ? I think this doesnt really matter on this example right?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to iterate the Array each time to find a free slot

You don't have to iterate through the array endlessly to check for free slots.

Let the Car notify you its index when it leaves the slot. When a car is about to enter, read the array for free slots. Once entered, mark out the index.

You may have a Car object which implements Runnable:

```
class Car implements Runnable{
    private int pos;    //index of array
}
```

Notification can be implemented using Observer pattern where you maintain a list of Cars. When a car leaves, notify its Observer.

Comment: and when the car leaves? there could be free slots everywehre in the array. I dont get the benefit of storing the index in the car class?

Comment: Storing of index is to facilitate automated notification which works hand in hand with Observer pattern. If it don't know its own position, how it able to notify the Observer?

Comment: Once the Observer is notified, it will be able to update your array immediately.

Answer (score 0):

How about a ParkingSpace class that has parkingNumber and occupied(boolean) and then you have a `List<ParkingSpace>`

```
class ParkingSpace implements Runnable {
    private int parkingSlot;
    private boolean occupied;
}
```

It is better to have the ParkingSlot tell you that it is occupied.

Answer (score 0):

There lots of different of approaches for such parking implementation which are can differ in terms of liveness and fairness. But for storing free parking places should be definitely used a queue. In terms of java if you use a blocking queue your tradeoff is fairness over liveness because underlying algorithm uses locks. For non-blocking queues tradeoff is liveness over fairness because underlying algorithm uses CAS instead of locks.

I think it would be reasonable to park cars in order according to the closest free place from the beginning of the parking. So PriorityQueue (underlying data structure is min-heap) can be used. CopyOnWriteArrayList is used as a thread-safe array.

```
  // a non blocking queue can be used instead of blocking
  private final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
  private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<ParkingPlace> places;

  public Parking(int numberOfPlaces) {
    places = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(numberOfPlaces, Integer::compareTo);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlaces; i++) {
      // preallocate
      places.add(null);
      queue.add(i);
    }
  }

  public static class ParkingPlace {
    private final long timeout;
    private final long id;

    public ParkingPlace(long timeout, long id) {
      this.timeout = timeout;
      this.id = id;
    }

    public long getTimeout() {
      return timeout;
    }

    public long getId() {
      return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "ParkingPlace{" +
          "timeout=" + timeout +
          ", id=" + id +
          '}';
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Parking parking = new Parking(5);
    int numOfCars = 12;
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfCars);
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfCars; i++) {
      executorService.submit(parking::park);
    }
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // ignored
    }
    System.out.println(parking.getState());
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  public void park() {
    long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    Integer place;
    try {
      System.out.println("Car with id " + id + " has come to the parking");
      // should be replaced with busy loop for non-blocking queue
      place = queue.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // ignore
      return;
    }
    long timeout = (new Random().nextInt(10) + 1) * 100L;
    System.out.println("Car with id " + id + " will park for " + timeout + " millis at place " + place);
    ParkingPlace parkingPlace = new ParkingPlace(timeout, id);
    try {
      places.set(place, parkingPlace);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(timeout);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // ignore
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      System.out.println("Car with id " + id + " has left the parking place " + place);
      // free place and return it back to queue
      places.set(place, null);
      queue.add(place);
    }
  }

  public List<ParkingPlace> getState() {
    return places;
  }
```